# Struts2 displaying json data on a jsp file with &quote

Tags: java, json, jsp, struts2, fullcalendar

Hi i am struggling to give JSON feed as event source to full calendar.I tried different methods but not worked for me(ex. return type as json in Struts2 it shows 500 error). Now i came up with a solution facing small issue like given below.

Codes and configurations-what i have

1) Action class with a property.

class JsonDemoAction{
  private String data; // have all needed code here like getters/setters method etc...
 }

2) In struts.xml maps result to jsondemo.jsp

3) content of jsondemo.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json"%>
     <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
     <s:property value="data"/>
```

Problem i am facing

1) The string data  has content

[{"id":1,"title":"Task in Progress1","start":"2013-12-28","end":"2013-12-29"},  {"id":2,"title":"Task in Progress2","start":"2013-12-26","end":"2013-12-28"}]

2) The jsondemo.jsp gives output

```
[{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Task in Progress1&quot;,&quot;start&quot;:&quot;2013-12-28&quot;,&quot;end&quot;:&quot;2013-12-29&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:2,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Task in Progress2&quot;,&quot;start&quot;:&quot;2013-12-26&quot;,&quot;end&quot;:&quot;2013-12-28&quot;}]
```

3) I need get the out put as double quote itself  not like `&quot;` what can i do for that?

4) if i hard code the json data directly into jsondemo.jsp  the calender displays events, no problem.

So finally 
"Can i avoid the conversion of " to `&quot`" 
is it problem of struts2?Is there any solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got answer,
change

```
<s:property value="data"/>
```

To

```
<s:property value="data" escapeHtml="false"/>
```

The problem is Struts2 escapes the " character in default , so i changed like escapeHtml="false"

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json"%>
```

To

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json;charset=UTF-8"%>
```